# Access to raw data in crypto USB device

Tags: windows, security, cryptography, usb

I have a crypto USB device which is used to store PKI certificates including the private key. 
It can be read/written to using the Microsoft Crypto APIs. And it is protected by a PIN. I am investigating if the device is in fact secure.

In my opinion, the security of the device hinges on how the PIN is used/stored. This is related to a different question I posted on crypto.stackexchange - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/crypto-usb-devices-where-is-the-pin-password-stored

When I insert the device into my USB slot, it presents itself as a CD drive containing a setup program which installs the driver/CSP middleware/UI for the device. After the setup program is run and I store certificates in the device, I still see only the setup program in Windows Explorer when I look at the drive assigned for the device.

So in order to prove that the device is secure or not secure, I want to access the raw data on the device. And I want to know what APIs on Windows, I can use to access the device bypassing the Crypto APIs.

Alternately are there tools to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to boot into a Linux Live CD and view the drive contents that way. You could, for example, try one of the latest Ubuntu builds, all of which can be run from the CD without installing the operating system onto your Windows machine.

My theory is that when your device is accessed from Linux, the raw data will be available. When it is accessed from Windows, I suspect some kind of clever AutoPlay comes into effect in order to present your device as a CD drive.

Comment: I don't get it - why would the files be viewable from a Linux Live CD?

Comment: "*When I insert the device into my USB slot, it presents itself as a CD drive containing a setup program which installs the driver/CSP middleware/UI for the device.*" <-- I assumed some kind of Windows cunningness was presenting your device in a particular way. I was suggesting in my answer that Linux is more likely to just show you the raw contents.